# ASP.NET 5 Session doesn't last?

Tags: asp.net-core, session-cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get sessions to work with ASP.NET 5, but they never store data.  It looks like every call is updating the session cookie to a new value and ignoring the cookie passed by the client.

Here's how I set them up in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`:

```
// Add framework services.
services.AddMvc();
services.AddCaching();
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.CookieName = "MySessionCookieName";
});
```

And I added this to `Configure` (prior to `app.UseMvc()` as instructed [here](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/)), and tried moving it to the top with the same result:

```
app.UseSession();
```

Trying to inject `ISession` gives an error, so I use `HttpContext.Session` like the docs say.  I wrote a simple api action that should set the current date to the 'now' session key, and do the same thing with memory cache which is injected:

```
sw.WriteLine("_Env.EnvironmentName: {0}", _Env.EnvironmentName);
sw.WriteLine("Keys: {0}", sess.Keys.Count());
sw.WriteLine("_Session['now'] (before update): {0}", sess.GetValue<DateTime>("now"));
sess.SetValue<DateTime>("now", DateTime.Now);
sw.WriteLine("_Session['now'] (after update): {0}", sess.GetValue<DateTime>("now"));

sw.WriteLine("Cache['now'] (before setting): {0}", _Cache.Get<DateTime>("now"));
_Cache.Set<DateTime>("now", DateTime.Now);
sw.WriteLine("Cache['now'] (after setting): {0}", _Cache.Get<DateTime>("now"));
```

While the memory cache works, the session middleware doesn't seem to.  When I keep reloading hte page, the "before" cache has a value, but the session is empty:

```
_Env.EnvironmentName: Development
Keys: 0
_Session['now'] (before update): 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
_Session['now'] (after update): 3/22/2016 1:55:30 AM
Cache['now'] (before setting): 3/22/2016 1:55:25 AM
Cache['now'] (after setting): 3/22/2016 1:55:30 AM
now: "2016-03-22T01:55:30.3029954-05:00"
```

Looking in the Chrome network tab, I see I'm passing the cookie with each request, but the response is always setting a new cookie.  Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Are `sess.GetValue<DateTime>()` and `sess.SetValue<DateTime>()` written by you?Just asking because in a new RC1 web app the session works with the configuration you described, although there are only extension methods for [strings and ints](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html?highlight=session#isession). In my test I tried using `Session.GetString` and `Session.SetString`

Comment: Yes, written by me.  All they do is serialize the type, and it works to pull the value after setting it (`_Session['now'] (after update)`).  Looking at the network tab it shows the session cookie is getting reset each time, so I think it must be something with that.

Comment: I created a new RC1 web application, configured the session as you did, and set/read value in the default Home/Index action. It's working fine, the first time the cookie is set and reloading the page sends the cookie so I see the values previously stored in the session. How are you calling your api action?

Comment: It's a get so I'm just using the URL in chrome.  In the network tab I see the session cookie is sent, but the response sets a different cookie.  The next call the set cookie is sent, but the response sets a new cookie.

Comment: I think it may have been due to my cookies somehow.  `Startup.cs` had `UseCookieAuthentication()` in there too.  We stopped using session 'cause I couldn't get it to work, but I was having trouble with the cookie authentication also.  I had like 10 cookies for `localhost:5000` from the session playing around and from unrelated projects (and Bamboo).  I cleared my cookies and the cookie authentication started working fine, though we aren't using session anymore so I can't say if that would have fixed it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Session without a problem on ASP.Net 5 RC1, update 1. The key problem I can see in your code is that you need to add all the session stuff ***before*** MVC in startup.cs.

Just for completeness, here is what I did based on the 'Web Application' template.

### Add Microsoft.AspNet.Session

Session requires the [Microsoft.AspNet.Session](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Session/) nuget package. To get it, add this to the `dependencies` section in your project.json

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

### In Startup.cs

Add these two lines before `services.AddMvc();` in `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`

```
services.AddCaching();
services.AddSession();
```

Add this before `app.UseMvc(...` in `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)`

```
app.UseSession();
```

### String to Byte[] Helpers

Right now, the Session object requires `byte[]` objects so everything needs to be converted to/from `byte[]`, so I setup these two helper functions:

```
static byte[] StringToBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}

static string BytesToString(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

### In my controller

Now the simple, bit.

To set Session

```
HttpContext.Session.Set("MySessionKey", StringToBytes("fibble"));
```

To read from Session

```
byte[] bytes;
HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("MySessionKey", out bytes);
var mySessionKeyValue = BytesToString(bytes);
```

### Want a working solution?

You can see all this code working in the following GitHub repo: https://github.com/martinkearn/How-Happy

Comment: Just one point of clarification,  `services.AddCaching();` and 
`services.AddSession();` don't need to come before `services.AddMvc()`, they can go before or after.  You can verify this by looking at the sample application code at: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/WebSites/BasicWebSite/Startup.cs  But it is true that `app.UseSession()` must come before `app.UseMvc(...`